# On demand asset compile Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I've some html5/ js game widgets that are shared between my webapp and my ipad app. I've used some ERB code here. The process is, whenever the user purchases a game from ipad, I copy all these assets to a temp folder, zip it and send it back.

Now the problem is, since I'm using ERB, the code is not compiled. This game widget folder is not a part of the asset pipeline as it is required only in certain  cases.

Is there a way I can compile these games on demand before copying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand, I'd say your problem lies with your use of ERB code

`ERB`, like `HTML`, can only be rendered by a specific technology stack (in our case Rails). This means you need all the other dependencies to make it work, which is where you're hitting problems

---

**Rails**

I would recommend your best bet is to create a Rails process to "compile" the JS for you

As a matter of speculation, I'd recommend you'll have to look at creating either a [`queued job`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/queuing-ruby-resque) or a [`scheduled`](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/scheduling) [`rake task`](http://railsguides.net/2012/03/14/how-to-generate-rake-task/) to do this:

- Create a special controller action
- Use the controller action to load required data
- Use a way to [create a ZIP file](http://thinkingeek.com/2013/11/15/create-temporary-zip-file-send-response-rails/)
- Save the file

If you'd like me to write some code (although I've never done it for this before), I'll have a look at it for you